# How do you determine if the target of an event is of a particular type

Tags: javascript

I have a listener attached to a parent element, within the function I want to find out if the click happened on an image child element.

```
function onClick(evt) {
    if (evt.target === ?)
```

I tried comparing the target to HTMLImageElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the `tagName` property:

```
var tag = event.target.tagName;
if (tag == 'BUTTON') { ... }
```

Keep in mind that for IE you'll need `srcElement`:

```
var elem = event.target || event.srcElement || { tagName: "?" };
var tag = elem.tagName;
```

Comment: `nodeName` might be more safe to use, though it should not matter in this example (it does when you blindly call any methods on `tagName`). The node name of element nodes is the same as their tag name and for text nodes it will be `#TEXT` afaik.

Comment: If I have two child elements which are both images, is it possible to find out which one the click occurred one when the listener is attached to the parent of them?